# Adjectives ending in 「〜やか」

Tags: etymology, adjectives

I recently came upon a number of adjectives ending in 「〜やか」that can be paired up with other adjectives:

> - 「緩い」 and 「緩**やか**」
> - 「涼しい」 and 「涼**やか**」
> - 「軽い」 and 「軽**やか**」

What is the meaning of this 「〜やか」and where does it come from? According to the dictionary, the paired adjectives have the same meaning. Is there a difference in tone between the adjectives?

Comment: There are also such adjectives, which cannot be paired any longer, but once were a pair, such as 穏い【おだい】 and 穏やか. (This appears to be true for practically all of these adjectives ending in ～やか, presumably from ～い + か.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, -い versions are i-adjectives but -やか versions are na-adjectives. Second, I feel -やか versions have slightly different primary meanings.

- 緩い【ゆるい】: loose, easy

  > 緩く引っ張る: to pull weakly
- 緩やか【ゆるやか】: gradual, slow

  > 緩やかに引っ張る: to pull slowly
- 軽い【かるい】: light (weight), light (mood), casual, easy, shallow (mind)

  > 軽く走る: to run for a short time, to run casually
- 軽やか【かろやか】: light (footstep), cheerful

  > 軽やかに走る: to run cheerfully, to run with light steps

I chose these examples to illustrate the difference, but there are times when they are interchangeable. 涼やか【すずやか】 is rare and I'm not sure how it's used.

I think やか is just another suffix used to make an adjective, and I doubt it has its own noteworthy meaning. It's no longer productive (i.e., new words using -やか are unlikely to be coined any more). As Earthliŋ mentioned, many (most?) -やか adjectives do not have their -い counterparts at least in modern Japanese (e.g., はなやか, みやびやか, ひそやか, しとやか).

When you encounter both -い and -やか versions, I think you should just remember them as different words. Just as you should distinguish *numeric* and *numerous*, or *temporary* and *temporal*, as two different words with different meanings.